# display Livedata using startLeScan()

Tags: android

Am working on developing an android app which scan the ble devices . I succeeded in scanning them and displaying the scanned response data packets. Now I have modified the ble to transmit scanned data packets which will change for each advertising events. So I need to display the live changing of data in my app.But as of once scan is pressed it will display the immediate value ,it will not update the next data ! am using the  `mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback)`  function . 
so  I need to start and stop scanning rapidly to display the new data.I tried to use multiple call of start and stop leScan but it hanged up the app.

Here is the generic function for scanning

private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {

```
    if (enable) {
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScanning = false;
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                System.out.println("hello");
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        mScanning = true;
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    } else {
        mScanning = false;
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it works fine in AOSP Lollipop. This Question is closed